# How can I use a regular expression to match words of a certain length but not urls?

Tags: regex

For text such as

```
Save Favorites & Share expressions with friends or the Community.
A full Reference & Help is available in the Library, or watch the video Tutorial.
expressions can start some lines though eventuallys
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
http://regexr.com/foo.html?q=bar
https://mediatemple.net
mediatemple.net
```

I want to select words tha are 11 digits long.

I can use

```
/\b[a-zA-Z]{11}\b/g
```

(http://regexr.com/3digk)

but it also matches the urls

```
https://mediatemple.net
mediatemple.net
```

How can I avoid that?  I use \b rather than a space to match at the start and end of lines

Comment: lookaround shoud do it for you. http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 1):

By using negative lookahead, you could exclude the words which have `.something` after them, this would exclude any URL and not touch the words in the end of the sentence (i.e. if a space is following the dot or the newline).

```
/\b[a-zA-Z]{11}\b(?!\.[^\s]+)/g
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [negative look behind expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to ensure that your match is not preceded by "://".

Answer (score 0):

Use `(?<!//)`, which is a negative look behind that asserts the preceding chars are not `"//"`:

```
/(?<!//)\b[a-zA-Z]{11}\b/g
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/Ie4GpttwUU).

If you want to be more specific and allow double slashes, eg `"foo//elevenchars"`, you can use 2 negative look behinds - one for each protocol (look behinds must match fixed length):

```
/(?<!http://)(?<!https://)\b[a-zA-Z]{11}\b/g
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/vb0b6WLsfl), matching `foo//elevenchars`, but not the urls.

Comment: But OP states that `mediatemple.net` is also a URL that shouldn't match.